# Operation on nth occurrence

Tags: sed

I want to perform substitutions on the nth occurrence of certain pattern with sed, for example:

```
echo 'abcd
aZcd' | sed 's/./Z/3;s/Z.*//'
```

the aim of this code is to delete chars after the 3 character. It is working for the first line, but not for the second line. The output is:

```
ab
a
```

how to fix this?

desired output:

```
ab
aZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working exactly as expected, because in your second command you substitute a `Z` and everything after it with an empty string. In your second input line, there's a `Z` at the second position, so only one character remains. To see that the substitution is working, you can add an `l` command in between:

```
$ echo 'abcd
aZcd' | sed 's/./Z/3;l;s/Z.*//'
abZd$
ab
aZZd$
a
```

To actually keep only three characters, you could do

```
$ echo -e 'abcd \naZcd' | sed 's/.//3g'
ab
aZ
```

Comment: the problem arises from : echo abcd | sed 's/.*//3' this code does'nt work for me.so i had to do substitution with a code.but what i posted show that the code used can be a part of the string.so how to get around this problem ?

Comment: @computer10 That is not the command I suggested. I suggested `sed 's/.//4g'`. Do you have any problems with this command? If so, please clarify.

Comment: how can i delete all characters after certain occurence? the code sed 's/.*//3' doesn't work for deleting all chars after the 3rd one.your code doesnt do that as well

Comment: @computer10 I don't get it. What is the desired output, exactly? Is it not what is shown in my answer? Please update the question then. What's your output when running my command?

Comment: @computer10 Okay, I assumed you wanted to keep 3 chars because you wrote "delete chars after the 3 character". I changed `4` to `3` in my answer to match the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/./\n/3;P;d' file
```

Use a newline as a marker and then print upto the marker and delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.\)\{3\}.*/\1/' YourFile
```

The `3` is the number of char you want to keep. Upper 256, use a pseudo counter due to limitation of sed buffer.

samplke of pseudo counter: 1024 char is `\(\(.\)\{256\}\)\{4\}\)`